# Is there an "initial memory allocation" different from the "limit" in Openshift/Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

In java, you have min heap space ( -Xms) and max heap space ( -Xmx). Min heap space is allocated to the JVM from start, "max heap space" is the limit where the JVM will say "out of heap space" when reaching it.

Are there such different values (initial and limit) for a pod in  Openshift/Kubernetes, or initial memory allocation is always equal to limit for some reason ?

Comment: can you elaborate on your question? maybe explain with a story or use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modern Java versions (those that support `+UseContainerSupport`), the heap allocation within a K8s or Openshift Pod is dependent on the memory available to the container.

This is solely determined by the "containers.resources.limits.memory" value (as you speculated). Other values, e.g. "containers.resources.requests.memory" don't play a part in this. If no resource limits are set, the entire memory of the respective cluster node will be used for initial heap size ergonomics, which is a sure recipe for OOM kills.

Comment: This is really interesting (even better if it's written in some official doc). So lets say my memory limit is 4 Go, so my min heap space is by default 25% of 4 Go = 1Go. What happens if my requests memory is set to 2 Go ? Btw, i'm not talking about allocation within the pod, I'm talking about allocation within the full cluster node.

Comment: From what I observed, memory resource.requests are ignored altogether - if you don't set limits, the JVM uses the total memory of the cluster node to perform ergonomics.

Comment: From what u say, I guess resource.requests is not allocated but is a requirement to start the container (there has to be that much of free memory).

Answer (score 1):

in K8s the resources are defined as request and limit.
the request is for the initial allocation and when the pod is reaching the memory limit it will get OOMKILLED  and afterwards will restart so i think its the same behaviour as you described.

Comment: But I've read that if requests memory is not used, it's available for other containers.